# How to calculate the time on planet B for an event that happened on planet A?

Tags: hard-science, time-keeping, galactic

We have had a number of "universal time" questions on this site — basically the various OPs have been looking for a way to establish a single time reference for the galaxy. I believe that's impractical, possibly not even useful, especially since it should be possible to calculate the time on planet B for an event that occurred on planet A. A solution for one planetary pair would be the stepping stone for a solution between any two planetary pairs — and thereafter the foundation for the programmatic concept (not the SI concept) of a "universal time."

**Conditions**

- Here on planet Earth, the Great Sovereign Emperor of the Known Universe, Malodorous a la Flatuleum de la Kineticist, was assassinated by Quaternary Admiral of the Galactic Fleet, Alistair "Big Dog" Alcott. "Big Dog" wants the empire to know about the change in fiefdom as quickly as possible.
- Now, the Fleet has access to <s>FTL</s>, <s>wormholes</s>, <s>bent space</s>, <s>super-Einsteinian physics</s>, <s>Clarkean magic</s>, really fast ships... but let's ignore that for the purpose of this question. Information simply cannot travel faster than the speed of light.
- But, whatever voodoo magic is used to transmit the information, it's receivable by every planet. How this happens is irrelevant.
- For the purpose of this question, the receiving planet happens to be a thoroughly terraformed Kepler-1047(c), known to its residents as *Plerte* (but was probably named "Planeta de la Muerte" by its original colonists...). Orbital period: 3.2 Earth days (and if that's not movin' the mail, nothing is), so that's "one year" on *Plerte.* We don't know it's rotational period, but let's claim for the sake of a lot of fun that it's 40 Earth hours and it's spinning *backward* during it's orbit compared to the spin of Earth in its orbit. Oh, and Kepler-1047 is 2,665.4 light years from Sol.
- To help everybody out, your answer can use [decimal time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_time).
- The message is sent at 2:27PM (GMT+12), September 19, 2020. In decimal time, that's 0.718965325567 of the Year of Our Glorious Emperor "Big Dog," 2020 (for convenience, let's say 2020.718965325567). You, the receiver on *Plerte* now know where it came from (Earth) and when it was sent — Earth time.
- One last thing: the converted time must be accurate to the "minute" (in decimal time, of course). So, 12 decimal points of accuracy.

**Question:** Assuming I've given you enough information... What equation would permit the local government on *Plerte* to convert the event date and time to *Plerte* local time?

*It's worth noting that at 2,665.4 light years it should be true that the two planets have changed position relative to one another by more than just one terrestrial minute — which is why I don't think this is a matter of simply counting backwards by 2,665.4 years. Especially since a "light year" is in reference to Earth.... heh, heh, heh....*

Oh... and don't forget that [hard-science](/questions/tagged/hard-science) tag....

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113203/discussion-on-question-by-jbh-how-to-calculate-the-time-on-planet-b-for-an-event).

Comment: I suggest what you are asking for, under the criteria that you have set, is, if not impossible, then certainl not trivial (there is more than one solution for x) . You discount simultaneity, FTL, instantaneous communications, and you state the information can not travel faster then the speed of light. Therefore, it is completely irrelevant as to the time on planet A that something happened on planet B, some several ligght years distant. Since you can not determine if something on planet A happened AT THE SAME TIME as something on planet B, why is it necessary to translate times?

Comment: There would, at the least, be one answer relative to planet A, and another answer relative to planet B, since it is impossible to establish or determine simultaneity. There would also be another answer relative to planet C, and so on. Time dilation just will not allow a trivial answer. In other words, there is no possibility, under your criteria, as an event happening on two planets several light years apart at the same time mutually relative to an observer on both planets.

Comment: So if there is no way to determine simultaneity, then there is no way to determine what happened on planet B at exactly time X (say, three years, two months, three days, five hours, 10 minutes ago) planet A time), since there will never BE a 'time X' on planet B relaticve to planet A..

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond There will never be a time "X" on planet B relative to planet A? I haven't had a chance to read through the various sources on simultaneity yet - but I know baloney when I hear it. By that logic, since there was never a time on Earth relative to the Big Bang, the estimated age of the universe is a universal hoax. What I've read so far about simultaneity suggests that you and AlexP are misapplying it. All it appears to suggest is that it's impossible to create a "universal time" for all planets, which is a truth that inspired this Q in the first place.

Comment: VTC because it feels like this is such a pure and simple physics problem you may as well just ask it on the physics stack exchange.

Comment: this is a physics problem phrased like a math problem on the wrong stack exchange for either
-1

Comment: I would bring your attention to the 'Ladder paradox' in simultaneity. Even IN THE SAME RELATIVISTIC FRAMEWORK, the 'at the same time' time is different between two places.  I presume that it is completely baloney. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladder_paradox I defer to @Ash in his/her answer for a description of why the times are different and can not be computed - too many variables, too many unknowns, too many equations, unless you ignore relativity as positied by Einstein.

Comment: @TonDay [Real world questions are permitted on this site](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6161/40609) otherwise 80% of the questions would need to be closed as physics, history, anthropology, etc. questions more suitably asked elsewhere.

Comment: @user2754 Ditto what I just explained to Ton Day.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond I draw your attention to the fact that I'm not asking that the time on Plerte reflect the precise moment of an event on Earth. I am asking how to convert a time reference from Earth into a meaningful reference on Plerte. And considering my post's first paragraph, Ash's answer is the first that actually has any value (in fact, it could be used in a good scifi story).

Comment: I am in total agreement that Ash's answer is competent, science-based, relevant, and pertinent. Much more fitting, however, to the question 'What are the pitfalls to any attempt to calculate the time on Planet B for an event that happened on Planet A, given the constraints and limits of Relativity as proposed by Einstein?' Using Quantum Mechanics principles, however, the question has a very different answer. You allude by your 'science-based' tag, without actually specifying it as a criteria, that all answers must adhere to Einstienian principles. I think that caused a lot of consternation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with the other commentators - this question is impossible to answer with the hard science tag because of the FTL. There's also a tonne of missing data which I've asked for in the comments but it isn't known. But, I can give you an overview of how this can be calculated once the true values are known, and assuming that both general and special relativity apply as observed in our universe in the relevant cases, and that your FTL drives only affect a special corner case that doesn't come into play and modify these results.

**Any periodic signal (eg a ticking clock) from planet A will not be periodic when observed on planet B**! 1 EarthSecond will not equal X PlerteSeconds at a constant rate.

This is due to [Special Relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity). Sol and Keplar 1047 are travelling around the milky way at orbital speeds around ~300km/s, and from either Suns frame of reference, the other sun will be accelerating, in a non linear way. A perfectly accurate equation would require a general solution to the [N-body problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-body_problem) for the entire Milky Way. This is an unsolved mathematical problem.

However for the purposes of time zone conversion within a galaxy we're not without hope. I [asked in the physics stackexchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/580736/would-time-dilation-make-it-impossible-to-accurately-convert-between-calendars-a/580776#580776) for some help, and the solution is to define a coordinate time as the standard, rather than measure time. This is how we've defined International Atomic Time vs UTC and such definitions scattered all over the galaxy can allow us to solve the problem.

#### The chain of clock definitions:

Your message is sent in GMT+12. (The Great Sovereign Emperor was killed in Nauru? Was he trying to sneak into Australia? That seems unlikely).

$$
GMT = GMT_{+12} - 0.0013689535
$$

Now we're in GMT. We need to go from GMT to UTC. These are very close, but [there's an error of about 0.9 seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time)

$$
UTC = GMT + GMT_{error}\\
GMT_{error} \approxeq 2.85198647 \cdot 10^{-8}
$$

Now, we need to get from UTC to TAI (International Atomic Time - French acronym). This is a weighted average of 400 atomic clocks over earth, and removes leap seconds.

The current formula is

$$
IAT = UTC + 0.00000117248
$$

Now we need to remove gravitational time dilation from the mass of Earth, so we need to convert to BCT (Barycentric Coordinate Time). This is a time on a hypothetical clock at the barycentre of the Earth Moon system. It's hypothetical as that's about 1500km under the surface. BCT has a scaling factor that applies since 1977 Jan 1st, as each year is 490 milliseconds too short.

$$
BCT = (IAT - 1977) * (1 + 1.550505 × 10^{−8}) + 1977
$$

We can't use GCT (Geocentric Coordinate Time) as then the mass of the moon will cause gravitation time shifting.

Now, this is the end of existing published physics, everything beyond here I'm making up.

We need to define:

- Sol System Barycentric Coordinate Time SSBCT

  - The time recorded on a hypothetical clock in the Solar Systems BaryCentre (which may be inside or just outside the sun depending on the planets orbits.).
  - No-one has defined this yet.
- Milky way Barycentric Coordinate Time MWBCT

  - The time recorded on a hypothetical clock in the Milky ways barycentre
  - We only know the distance accurate to a few thousand light years, so there is no way we can define this clock now.
  - This conversion is non linear, as we need to take into account special relativity of the motion of Sol.
  - Sol probably doesn't keep a constant velocity in the milky way, so this will have trig and calculus to determine the speed at the exact moment in orbit.
- Keplar1047 Barycentric Coordinate Time K1047BCT

  - The time recorded on a hypothetical clock in the Keplar1047 barycentre. Which is probably also in the sun, but we don't know.
  - This conversion is non linear, as we also need to take into account special relativity from the motion of Keplar 1047.
- Plerte Barycentric Coordinate Time PBCT

  - The time recorded on a hypothetical clock in the centre of the system of Plerte and its moon(s, if any).
- Plerte UTC - PTUC. Getting back to a standard of time on the planets surface thats kinda useful.

  - This will correct for general relativity.
- Plerte Local time at your city on the surface or whatever. The answer.

To work out the time, your inhabitants of plerte will need to do some maths, first thing:

- Forget about the time the message arrived in plerte local time. Over the 2600 years the galaxy has change so much that the path the message followed has changed length a non-trivial amount.
- Convert the time in the messsage from GMT+12, to GMT, to UTC, to IAT, to BCT, to SSBCT, and then finally to the galactic central time. MWBCT.
- Convert that time from MWBCT, to K1047BCT, to PBCT, to PUTC, to Local time.

And then marvel at the peice of trivia you now know. It was ~304224 PlerteYears ago, and you now know it to the Plerteminute, congratulations. This is equivalent in Earth culture to me knowing the exact time to the minute that Assurbanipal succeeds his father Esarhaddon as king of Assyria in 669 BC. (I'm very popular at parties).

Comment: 'have trig and calculus to determine the speed at the exact moment in orbit...' such trig and calculus functions, I presume, based on the  Milky Way Barycenter at that precise moment? But a trig function? Wouldn't this be a 3D function? Polar co-ordinates, in a sphere, not a circle? And wouldn't the Solar Systems BaryCentre constantly change, as asteroids come and go into the system? It seems to me that even the Barycentric Coordinate Time would have to be adjusted, as asteroids and meteors approach too close to the earth-moon orbit.

Comment: 'And then marvel at the peice of trivia you now know.' Or collect your prize winnings in some intergalactic trivia game like 'Jeopardy' or 'Who Wants to be a Millionaire'. Decisions of the judges are final.

Comment: 'Milky Way Barycentric Coordinate Time MWBCT' as stars come into and out of existence, and black holes continuously form, change size, and such, changing matter into energy and energy into mattter, and given that we have no idea how black matter works, isn't this also a constantly changing place? Otherwise, couldn't it be used as the origin in a universal 3D galactic co-ordinate navigation system?

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond MWBCT would need some calibration, probably not as much as you think. (Stars don't form out of nothing - they came from existing mass, the mass was already there it just changed function). But a calibration will be needed just as we calibrate UTC for events on Earth. NASA scientists calculated that the water stored in the Three Gorges Dam has increased the length of Earth's day by 0.06 microseconds. That's a leap second every 54 years just because of that one dam.

Comment: But aren't stars continuously changing matter into energy, in some super-hyped method of fusion and fission? As stars form and die, this rate is adjusted. As black holes collapse, huge aounts of energy are released. Calculated over the entire galaxy, that is a lot of mass conversion, methinks. The calibration would need to incorporate some adjustment for the rate of conversion?

Comment: So THAT is why my watch is off, and why I was late? That damned dam.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond Yeah there would need to be a correction factor for that. It will not be a simple formula. And that mass loss also affects general relativity of the stars - it will be a lot of work to derive.

Comment: The game show contestants on Planet Z, several hundred light years more distant, as the crow flies, from Planet B is from Planet A, would not even understand the question. To them, the event has not yet occured on Planet A, because the information has not reached them. That is, if the information has not reached them, to them it has not occured. Bummer to be a contestant on Planet Z.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond Unless the asteroids and meteors are something of the size of the moon - they're irrelevant. I'm not interested in time calculations to the femtosecond or worse region.

Comment: Ash, yours is to date the only serious answer. Part of the point of asking the question was helping users understand the challenges involving a universal time system. Completely secondary is the fact that a "galactic empire" is almost meaningless unless there's a fundamental change in how we understand physics because an argument could be made that no information is so valuable that you must know it at only the speed of light over interstellar distances. In some cases, even at interplanetary distances (an idea that was used successfully in the movie *The Martian*).

Comment: However, once again, I expressed in the question the fact that whatever drives my ships is to be ignored. It's been educational (given that I recently posted a [meta question about dealing with back stories](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8008/40609)) watching how people just can't let go of things.

Comment: @JBH The Twin Gorges dam accumulating a discrepancy of one leap second in 54 years, and you are talking about an error correction over thousands of yars? Seems to me, just the water behind the dam would put you off by one minute in 540 years, the accuracy that you are looking for.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond That's a good point, and hopefully something that Ash will expand on in his answer. ("It's impractical to be accurate to the minute because of the following [tag:hard-science] reasons....")

Comment: I think Ash has had enough relativity for the moment....

Comment: Like I said, damned dam. Botches everything up. Reality meets fiction. Nothing can destroy a great theory like a ruthless gang of facts.

Answer (score 3):

Your world has FTL ships, therefore in your world relativity works differently from how it works in our world as science currently understands it, therefore no [hard-science](/questions/tagged/hard-science) answer can be given. This is the only possible answer to your question as it currently stands.

There *is* an answer, within relativity theory, to the question of how to precisely determine simultaneity within a given reference frame. You can find the details of this [here, on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_of_simultaneity), for example, and it works not only if the planets are moving relative to each other, but also if they are accelerating. The primary reference for that would most likely be Einstein's 1905 paper, "Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter Körper", of which you can find an English translation [here](http://www.fourmilab.ch/etexts/einstein/specrel/specrel.pdf). (Of course, in relativity the notion of simultaneity depends on the reference frame, but in your case that's ok, because you're only interested in the reference frame of planet B.)

However, in a world in which ships can travel faster than light without causing time paradoxes, there must be some kind of universal preferred reference frame, or some other modification to relativity, in order to make that possible. Consequently, in such a world, it's unlikely that people would calculate simultaneity the same way we do. They would instead use whatever made-up physics exists in your world to make FTL possible.

Comment: I specifically excluded FTL ships to focus on only-light-speed travel (aka, electromagnetic radiation). You are incorrect that an answer cannot be given. The more I look at simultaneity, the more I believe you're using it incorrectly.

Comment: @JBH you didn't exclude FTL ships, you specifically mentioned them. You told us to ignore them, but as I said, that's not possible. It's not the possibility of using them that's the issue, it's *the fact that they exist at all*, which basically messes up relativity completely, as I keep trying to tell you. And no, I am not using simultaneity incorrectly.

Comment: (If someone has the rep to vote to close this question I think that should be done. The question has the [tag:hard-science] tag but is based on a fundamentally non hard science premise, which the OP is not interested in fixing or even really understanding.)

Comment: We've had this argument before... "but let's ignore that for the purpose of this question. Information simply cannot travel faster than the speed of light" is ***completely clear.*** Your unwillingness to not focus on the question with the expressed limitations is challenging. You're treating the fun back story as if it has equal weight with the question. ***That's never true.*** If you can provide a hard-science [frame challenge](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7097/40609), please do! That would be a valid answer.

Comment: This answer is a hard science frame challenge. That's what it is.

Comment: Anyway, here's a pro tip if you ever do anything that involves writing for a living: clarity is judged by the *readers*, not the author. If a reader tells you the writing was unclear, that means it was unclear to at least one reader --- which means it was unclear.

Comment: No, Nathaniel. ***It is not.*** You have provided a couple of links, but link-only answers have never been acceptable on Stack Exchange. You need to provide a full and complete answer that uses links and other references as citations (not as answers in and of themselves). At this time, this answer is nothing more than a complaint. And as to your "pro tip." I'm a technical writer with more than 10,000 pages of experience. Let me offer an alternative pro tip: you're on a site that focuses on *fiction.* There are other sites more appropriate for your rigid views.

Comment: My answer is as follows: Your world has FTL ships, therefore in your world relativity works differently from how it works in our world as science currently understands it, therefore no hard-science answer can be given. This is the only possible answer to your question as it currently stands.

Comment: The rest is clarification.

Comment: That earned you a flag.

Comment: There is no point in explaining in any detail how simultaneity works in relativity theory, because *relativity theory does not apply in your world*. That is the only possible answer to your question as posed.

Comment: @Nathaniel out of curiosity, since you are seems to believe this question is worth closure, why did you answer it?

Comment: It seems to me that this discussion has descended into anarchy, and has become cyclic and redundant. It is the 'Ladder paradox' with the two relativistic frameworks arguing that 'the ladder fits'. 'no it doesn't' 'relativity applies' 'no it doesn't'. Seems to me the arguements on both sides are moot. You can not argue for 'hard science' and 'fiction' at the same time. It is this criteria that is the sticking point 'But, whatever voodoo magic is used to transmit the information, it's receivable by every planet. How this happens is irrelevant. No, it is NOT irrelevant. See end of @Ash answer.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond Actually, Ash's answer points out that the time conversion is possible. Whether or not it's *useful* to know the information is not part of the question. No one has asked about how the information was transmitted - the entire argument has been, "you mentioned FTL, it doesn't matter that you said to ignore it, the fact that you mentioned it means this is impossible to answer." Which is why I [asked in meta about challenging back stories](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8008/40609). ([See also this](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8011/40609).)

Comment: What I meant by 'the end of Ash's answer' was the relevance part - determining an event timeline down to the minute for an event that has just been brought to your attention, but that happened thousands of years ago on another planet, is pertinent how? It only has relevance and application to any event or to the history of your planet from the time it became known on your planet. It is that 'simultaneity' and 'instatnaneous communications' thing, and the conflict with the 'hard science' tag..

Comment: And the explanation of why it is impossible, as outlined in the comments to Ash's answer, to determining the time for an event that happened on another planet thousands of years, and perhaps thousands of light years away, on another planet, down to a 'minute'. The inherent cumulative error in calculating all of the compensatory 'adjustments',  over thousands of years, makes the margin of error far outside the limits of 'one minute'. Unless, of course, that you allow for 'instantaneous communication', which you have specifically excluded, but referenced as 'voodoo magic'.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond I don't think it's impossible, I just think it's irrelevant. If you have FTL then there is some other, different, way of calculating simultaneity, which is different from any known to our early 21st century science. There has to be, in order to avoid time paradoxes - FTL can't work without it. It would be possible for people to calculate simultaneity the Einstein way - they're an advanced society and I'm sure they can counter for all errors - but there's no reason why they *would*, because what's relevant for *them* is the global reference frame their ships move in.

Comment: OOOps that comment was directed towards JBH, but I failed to direct it properly. The problem becomes moot if you allow Quantum concepts, and entanglement, and the fact that everything is just a probability curve. However, the strict adherence to Einsteinian theories was alluded to, but not stated directly as a criteria. The hard science tag usually implies it on this site. The coolest theory that is being entertained is that causality can be from the future to the present, if indeed time is reversible.

Answer (score 0):

You can't come up with "an" equation, because you haven't provided sufficient information to cover everything: what's the relative velocity between Kepler-1047 and Sol? How deep in the gravity well of the star is the planet? What's the planet's mass?

That said, in principle, the solution is relatively easy, if requiring multiple calculations. If you know the relative velocities between Sol and Kepler-1047, you can calculate the relativistic effects caused by that. Assume the message is transmitted at light speed, so that's a fixed velocity which both would measure the same which makes that part easy. You can calculate the time dilation effects caused by the gravity well of each star, and each planet, and therefore you can determine that if an event happened at time X on Earth, taking all that into account, when word reaches Kepler-1047(c) they can calculate back to determine it would have happened at time Y in their system.

Oh, and you'd need to take into account where each is in the galaxy's gravitational well, and so on.

Comment: I'm sure it's true that I need to track down additional information - but that's a comment, not an answer.

Comment: "There is no equation based on the provided information" is an answer to the question "What equation would permit the local government on Plerte to convert the event date and time to Plerte local time?" You're asking for a solution to a question that cannot be answered without a hell of a lot more information than has been provided, or anyone is likely to know.

Comment: Additionally, if you use light, you would need to incorporate information on every gravity source along the way, because each gravity source would 'lens; the light beam in some fashion, changing the length of the journey, and thus the time.

Comment: @KeithMorrison The [tag:hard-science] tag requires more than "I can't answer it, and I don't believe anyone else can, either." This site regularly requires the respondents to come up with necessary information. I'm not an astronomer nor an astrophysicist - which is one of the reasons I asked the question.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond That's what makes the question a challenge. Which suggests another question. thanks!

Comment: "What is the exact number of loving cells in your body at 12:00:00 UTC on May 5, 2017?" is a question that is also challenging, clearly has a defined answer (after all, one could, in principle, count them), and yet is impossible to answer.